# JavaFX-maven project suddenly stopped recognizing resources on InteliJ IDE

Tags: java, maven, javafx, resources

Yesterday my JavaFX-maven project was working fine in InteliJ IDE, but packed JRE with maven javaFX:jlink command was throwing similar exeption to this one I`ve got today with javaFX:run command:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1125)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:618)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:194)
at org.example/org.example.GameMenu.construct(GameMenu.java:20)
at org.example/org.example.App.start(App.java:23)
```

The code that throws exeption:

```
public class GameMenu {
static int picOfChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
public static Font font = Font.loadFont(Objects.requireNonNull(GameMenu.class.getResource("/utility/pixRectv2.ttf")).toExternalForm(), 48);
public static Font font2 = Font.loadFont(Objects.requireNonNull(GameMenu.class.getResource("/utility/pixRectv2.ttf")).toExternalForm(), 32);
public static Group menu = new Group();

public static Group construct() {
    menu = new Group();
    ImageView logo = new ImageView("menu/logo3.png");
    Image backg3 = new Image("backg/backgPL" + picOfChoice + ".png", winWidth, winHeight, false, false);
    ImageView backgV3 = new ImageView(backg3);
    menu.getChildren().add(backgV3);

    logo.setX(0);
    logo.setY(0);
    menu.getChildren().add(logo);//Logo is on top
    return menu;
}}
```

No code on that line was changed. Resources folder was not moved. pom.xml wasnt changed. Those png`s are accesible for R/W and
[even recognized by IDE as images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrPPh.png)

I have tried different path formatting (absolute path included) and it did not help. But ImageView logo = new ImageView("file:menu/logo3.png"); loads no image, while not throwing any exeption.

I have tried opening my other javaFX projects and they all work, while using similar project structure and similar way of useing new ImageView(). I have created new project with javaFX and it loads images just fine, so I wasnt able to recreate this problem.

I have opened this project on other machines, it throws same exeptions.
Fonts of javaFX in code above still load fine. Similar way of loading images ( through GameMenu.class.getResource ) works too.

The question: How to fix it and how to avoid it in future?

[My project folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzpAN.png)

***UPD:***
Thanks to @James_D and @Dmitriy Popov for answers;

I have added new method for path extraction via widely used .class.getResource()

So fixed code looks like

```
        ImageView logo = new ImageView(Utility.getImageRes("/menu/logo3.png"));
```

Where Utility.getImageRes(String) is

```
    public static String getImageRes(String path) {
   return Objects.requireNonNull(Utility.class.getResource(path)).toExternalForm();
}
```

It works now, both with javaFX:run and jlink commands. Reason why previous method stopped working is still unknown.

Comment: Could you please clarify, what code is on these lines:
`at org.example/org.example.GameMenu.construct(GameMenu.java:20)
at org.example/org.example.App.start(App.java:23)`?

Comment: @Dmitriy Popov,
 at org.example/org.example.GameMenu.construct(GameMenu.java:20) line is `ImageView logo = new ImageView("menu/logo3.png");`
at org.example/org.example.App.start(App.java:23) line is  `sceneMM = new Scene(GameMenu.construct(), winWidth, winHeight);`

Comment: Ok, than the problem is just that the file is not found by the relative URL `"menu/logo3.png". Try with an absolute path and then debug to check from which root directory does your code take the relative path.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other helps.

Comment: @James_D Thank you, I have migrated my project to `.class.getResource(path)` as advised by your link. Reason why previous solution stopped working is still unknown.